# TYPO3 8.7.15 include typoscript does not work on constants.typoscript

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap, typo3, typoscript, typo3-8.x

I want to build a Test Site with Typo3, Bootstrap_package & the News extension.
When I try to load my own constants and setup typoscripts the constants are not working.

I use this to load my scripts

```
<INCLUDE_TYPOSCRIPT: source= "DIR:fileadmin/Typoscript/" extensions="typoscript">
```

The Typoscript folder contains a setup and a constants file. Inside the setup, I got all the template paths and they work fine. But inside the constants, I want to use

```
page.theme.copyright.enable = 0
```

as an example but it does not change anything and I don't know why.

**UPDATE**: looks like it has something to do with

```
page.theme.copyright.enable = 0
```

because `config.contentObjectExceptionHandler = 0` works fine and is loading properly

Comment: Are you sure that path and suffix are correct? You entered "typoscript" as suffix. If everything is correct and also file-rights allow the server access, then try is with the suffix `txt`, you just have to change the filenames accordingly.

Comment: Hey, David. Yes, I got typoscript as a suffix there. I also tested it with text and without any suffix. Still does not load the constants file.

Comment: Then you've adjust file-ownership and / or file-rights, that the webserver can access them

Comment: Don't forget to check the folder-owner and folder-rights too and adjust them if required

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where do you have the include statement?

I assume you have one include statement in the setup area. Then you will include all the files into the typoscript setup. you will have some additional values but there are no constants. It even may be problematic as the constants might have the same pathes as the resulting values.

You need own include statements for constant area and for setup area. And be aware to separate the includes by matching selection.

constants:

```
<INCLUDE_TYPOSCRIPT: source= "DIR:fileadmin/Typoscript/" extensions="constants.typoscript">
```

setup:

```
<INCLUDE_TYPOSCRIPT: source= "DIR:fileadmin/Typoscript/" extensions="setup.typoscript">
```

or:

constants:

```
<INCLUDE_TYPOSCRIPT: source= "DIR:fileadmin/Typoscript/Constants/" extensions="typoscript">
```

setup:

```
<INCLUDE_TYPOSCRIPT: source= "DIR:fileadmin/Typoscript/Setup/" extensions="typoscript">
```

Comment: Thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 0):

Check it once in your folder contains all file with `.typoscript` extension or check `DIR` paths is correct?

Because of you have to specify the file extension `.typoscript` in your include typoscript. So, if any file contains without `.typoscript` extension in your folder then it's not included.